# Why is exponential integrator method giving poor results?

Tags: matlab, octave, julia, differential-equations, runge-kutta

```
//u' + Au = g(t,u) can be solved by exponential integrators also
//Following snippet is for exp INtegrators
A = -full(Strang(11)) 
A[end,1]=1;A[1,end]=1;
g(t,u) = 2-u
u0 = zeros(11);u0[6]=1
nsteps = 1000
tmax = 10.0
h = tmax/nsteps
u = u0
t = 0
for k in 1:nsteps
    u = expm(-h*A)*u + h*((expm(-h*A)-1)\(-h*A))*g(t,u)
    t = k*h
end
//this is for euler's method
for k in 1:nsteps
    u += h*(A*u + h*g(t,u))
    t = k*h
end
```

## Why are they giving poor results?

### The method is exploding very badly, it should converge to [1.99]*11 , or something like that?

Is there any mistake while implementing Exp Integrator?

Comment: Can you check the signs in the matrix exponentials, currently they look like the original ODE is `u' = A*u + g(t,u)`. Perhaps the result is because you are integrating backward in time.

Comment: Yes I tried changing the sign also but its answer is still varying for that calculated by Euler method

Comment: @LutzL is there something wrong with the implementation? Cuz the formula seems correct?

Comment: No, the formula is wrong by a symbol, you switched the factors resp. direction in the division, see answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integrator 
I tried to implement equation 2

Comment: Read further down at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integrator#First-order_forward_Euler_exponential_integrator. Also note that in Matlab `A/B == A*inv(B)` and `A\B == inv(A)*B`.

Comment: Your Euler method also has a factor `h` too much, should be `u += h*(A*u + g(t,u))` and corresponds to `u'=Au+g`.

Comment: What exactly is `Strang`? The tridiagonal matrix of the discretization of the second derivative?

Comment: Strang(11) gives a matrix in julia that has diagonals = -2 and elements next to diagonals are 1 ie (i+1,i) and (i,i+1) for all except the left and the right corner

Comment: Then you are missing the denominator `dx^2` of the differential/difference quotient. The PDE if I read it correctly should be the reaction-diffusion equation `u_t = u_{xx} + (2-u)` which indeed will converge towards the constant `2`. You could also assemble all of `u_{xx}-u` in the linear part.

Comment: Yes that's a reaction-diffusion and it should converge to 2, But I didn't get the other part, can you please share with me the Matlab code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test problem is a singular matrix. A better test is the setup:

```
using SpecialMatrices
A = -full(Strang(11))
g(t,u) = 2-u
u = zeros(11);u[6]=1
nsteps = 10000
tmax = 1.0
h = tmax/nsteps
t = 0
```

Using this, fix the `h` in the Euler to get (notice there's an extra `h`, my bad:

```
u = zeros(11);u[6]=1
for k in 1:nsteps
    u += h*(A*u + g(t,u))
    t = k*h
end
@show u

u = [0.93573,1.19361,1.26091,1.29627,1.34313,1.37767,1.34313,1.29627,1.26091,1.19361,0.93573]
```

But to find out what's wrong, start looking at numbers. What happens A=0? Well, we know that `phi(z) = (e^z - 1)/z`. By L'Hopital's rule, `phi(z) -> 1` as `z->0`. Therefore, in order for our implementation to have the same behavior, we have to have that same result. But let's check what happens:

```
expm(zeros(5,5))

5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Notice that this gives the identity matrix. So think about the limit: if the bottom is going to zero... how can this be constant? We must have that the top is going to zero... so the top is going to `I`.

And that's the moment of clarity: the author meant `1` in the field that you're in. So for a matrix input, `1=I`. When you realize that, you fix the code:

```
# Norsett-Euler
u = zeros(11);u[6]=1
for k in 1:nsteps
  u = expm(h*A)*u + ((expm(h*A)-I)/A)*g(t,u)
  t = k*h
end
@show u

u = [0.935722,1.1936,1.26091,1.29627,1.34313,1.37768,1.34313,1.29627,1.26091,1.1936,0.935722]
```

Moral of the story: for programming mathematics, you also have to debug your math.

### Edit

Get a more efficient form one step at a time. First, try and force another varphi term:

```
# Norsett-Euler
u = zeros(11);u[6]=1
for k in 1:nsteps
  u = (I + A*(expm(h*A)-I)/A)*u + ((expm(h*A)-I)/A)*g(t,u)
  t = k*h
end
@show u
```

Now gather:

```
# Norsett-Euler
u = zeros(11);u[6]=1
for k in 1:nsteps
  u = u + ((expm(h*A)-I)/A)*(A*u + g(t,u))
  t = k*h
end
@show u
```

This is the efficient form of the method you were trying to write. Then you can cache the operator since A is constant:

```
# Norsett-Euler
u = zeros(11);u[6]=1
phi1 = ((expm(h*A)-I)/A)
for k in 1:nsteps
  u = u + phi1*(A*u + g(t,u))
  t = k*h
end
@show u
```

Answer (score 0):

The [exponential Euler-Rosenbrock step should be](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Exponential_integrator&oldid=773167521#First-order_forward_Euler_exponential_integrator) for `u'=Lu+g(t,u)`

```
u = expm(h*L)*u + ((expm(h*L)-1)/L)*g(t,u)
```

Note that the inverted matrix is `L` (in Matlab `A/B == A*inv(B)` and `A\B == inv(A)*B`), and there is no naked `h` in the formula. In your case, `L = -A`.

---

An alternative method to split off the exponential part has is as follows. Set `u(t) = exp(-t*A)*v(t)` which translates into the differential equation

```
exp(-t*A)*v'(t) = g(t,exp(-t*A)*v((t))
```

Now apply the forward Euler step for `v`

```
v(t+h) = v(t) + h * exp(t*A)*g(t,exp(-t*A)*v((t))
```

which translated back into terms in `u` gives

```
u(t+h) = exp(-(t+h)*A)*v(t+h) 
       = exp(-h*A) * ( u(t) + h * g(t,u(t)) )
```

This should equally result in a first order method.

Comment: I was trying to implement exponential rk method, but before that Was thinking of trying exp integrators to solve the same,
eq 1.6 of this paper https://na.math.kit.edu/download/papers/acta-final.pdf

Comment: Tried your upper part of the answer but its still giving the wrong result!! @LutzL